# How can I log users activity

Tags: .net, asp.net

I'm using default ASP.NET user controls and SQL user provider.

How can I log somewhere when users login to web and when logout ?

Is there some tricks for it or just write to some .log file manually each time after user login. (Also , how can I check user IP adress ?)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASP.NET `Login` control has a `LoggedIn` event that you can add a handler for that does whatever you like, such as log it somewhere.  Similarly, the `LoginStatus` control has a `LoggedOut` event.

The User IP address is available using the HttpContext: `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;` or `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];`

Answer (score 1):

To log the logins you will need to handle the LoggedIn event and write to your log there. You can either manually set up a log or use an [existing framework.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126540/what-is-your-net-logging-framework-of-choice)

You have a few different options for getting the users IP:

```
Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR");
Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
Request.UserHostAddress();
```